# Converting Set<BluetoothDevice> to BluetoothDevice[]

Tags: android

Here are 2 parts of my program

1.

```
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;
BluetoothDevice[] pairedDevicesArray;
```

2.

```
pairedDevices = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
//pairedDevicesArray = (BluetoothDevice[]) pairedDevices.toArray();
```

The problem is with the commented line.Uncommenting it makes my app stop.Is it not possible convert the above `Set` into an `array` so that I can access `BluetoothDevice` objects in the `array` randomly.

New to Java and android

Update: Using `pairedDevicesArray = pairedDevices.toArray(new BluetoothDevice[0]);` instead of above commented line solves the problem.What's the difference?

Comment: Thank you so much. pairedDevicesArray = pairedDevices.toArray(new BluetoothDevice[0]); is the saving grace.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get the `Set` contents as array as you have tried. You need to check the returned value of `getBondedDevices` to be non-null. As per the documentation, [`BluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#getBondedDevices%28%29) can return `null` in case of error.

```
pairedDevices = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
if(null != pairedDevices){
    pairedDevicesArray = (BluetoothDevice[]) pairedDevices.toArray();
}
```